# How to prevent manual changes to AWS infrastructure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have read Terraform Up and Running book and in this one there is "Golden rule" which states that if we use Terraform then no manual changes should be done to infrastructure. The only changes that are allowed are the ones that are performed using terraform apply.

How to preserve this using AWS as cloud provider so that only rules applied by Terraform can be applied without any manual changes?

Comment: Just lock down the AWS account so the only user/role with access it the Terraform one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. remove IAM permissions for modification from non-root-user IAM roles.
2. create a specific IAM role for terraform
3. use a CI/CD system like Atlantis to run your terraform
4. Trigger Atlantis off commits to your main branch.

This means that if you need to make manual changes (for e.g to recover a system) then you can make use of the root account (or, preferably, a designated IAM role with superuser credentials that only trusted users may assume).  All other changes go through an automated system, removing the need for users to be able to run terraform locally.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a very subjective question and the answers could vary depending on certain constraints (especially IAM strategy) but since you asked, I can help you with some of the ideas:

- [Disable AWS Management Console access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_management_console_access.html#console_disable) - Beware that it could be counterproductive as people won't be able to test/fail quickly. Not everything has to be automated and sometimes you just need to validate a quick POC without the IaC shenanigans. Also, IAM users (with programmatic access) would still be able to create resources via CLI/other means and not necessarily just Terraform. I wouldn't recommend it personally.
- Provide Read Access to everyone. Create an IAM role specifically created for Terraform (without console access) and allow everyone to assume it. Or you can also utilize AWS Organizations [Service control policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) to restrict resource creation to this role only. Still, users can assume the role to create resources without Terraform.
- Define what are the needs of your Org and break it down into reusable modules that can be easily consumed by the developer teams without a steep learning curve. Build those modules in a manner that teams are confident enough to contribute once they get hold of it. Help build a culture of knowledge sharing and in the end, use a tool like [driftctl](https://github.com/cloudskiff/driftctl) to detect, track and alert on infrastructure drifts. This is actually my preferred approach.

Having said what I said, I would ask you to question your objective behind this exercise because this goal seems a bit too restrictive and unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I really like the idea behind driftctl :)